# Dynamically Update The Stock Ticker Array When I Add More Stocks

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing, stock

Here is the code that I have so far. I created a blank ticker array and then a new variable called tickerIndex and use ticker(tickerIndex) to locate a specific stock ticker within the data. I use that specific data point to add up all the volumes and find the starting and ending prices for that stock and find the return. But when I run it, it only shows the headers :(.

```
Sub AllStockAnalysis()

    Worksheets("All Stocks Analysis").Activate

    tickerIndex = 0
    totalVolume = 0
    Dim ticker() As String
    Dim startTime As Single
    Dim endTime As Single
    Dim yearValue As String
    Dim endingPrice As Double
    Dim startingPrice As Double
    RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    yearValue = InputBox("What year would you like to run the analysis on?")

    startTime = Timer
    Sheets(yearValue).Activate

    For i = 2 To RowCount
        
        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Or Cells(i - 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            Cells(i, 1).Value = ticker(tickerIndex)
            End If
        
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = ticker(tickerIndex) Then
            totalVolume(tickerIndex) = totalVolume(tickerIndex) + Cells(i, 8).Value
            End If
        
        If Cells(i - 1, 1).Value <> ticker(tickerIndex) And Cells(i, 1).Value = ticker(tickerIndex) Then
            startingPrice = Cells(i, 3).Value
            End If
            
        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ticker(tickerIndex) And Cells(i, 1).Value = ticker(tickerIndex) Then
            endingPrice = Cells(i, 6)
        
        
            Sheets("All Stocks Analysis").Cells(i + 2, "A").Value = ticker(tickerIndex)
            Sheets("All Stocks Analysis").Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = totalVolume(tickerIndex)
            Sheets("All Stocks Analysis").Cells(i + 2, "C").Value = endingPrice / startingPrice - 1
            totalVolume = 0
            tickerIndex = tickerIndex + 1
        End If
        
    
    Next i
        
    Worksheets("All Stocks Analysis").Activate
    Range("A1").Value = "All Stocks (" + yearValue + ")"
    Cells(3, 1).Value = "Ticker"
    Cells(3, 2).Value = "Total Daily Volume"
    Cells(3, 3).Value = "Return"
    endTime = Timer
    MsgBox "This code ran in " & (endTime - startTime) & " seconds for the year " & (yearValue)
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` before `Sheets(yearValue).Activate` so are getting the row count of the analysis sheet (because of the first line `Worksheets("All Stocks Analysis").Activate`).

Not sure what your year spreadsheet column A is like but try this

```vb
Sub AllStockAnalysis1()

    Dim ticker()
    Dim tickerIndex As Long, rowcount As Long, i As Long

    Dim startTime As Single
    Dim endTime As Single
    Dim endingPrice As Double
    Dim startingPrice As Double
    
    Dim yearValue As String
    yearValue = InputBox("What year would you like to run the analysis on?")
    startTime = Timer
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(yearValue)
        rowcount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim ticker(1 To rowcount, 1 To 3)
    
        For i = 2 To rowcount
                         
            ' start
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value <> .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
                tickerIndex = tickerIndex + 1
                ticker(tickerIndex, 1) = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            End If
            
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = ticker(tickerIndex, 1) Then
                ' total volume
                ticker(tickerIndex, 2) = ticker(tickerIndex, 2) + .Cells(i, 8).Value
                 
                ' first record
                If .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value <> ticker(tickerIndex, 1) Then
                     startingPrice = .Cells(i, 3).Value
                End If
                 
                ' last record
                If .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ticker(tickerIndex, 1) Then
                     endingPrice = .Cells(i, 6)
                     ' return
                     ticker(tickerIndex, 3) = endingPrice / startingPrice - 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
        
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All Stocks Analysis")
        .Range("A1").Value = "All Stocks (" + yearValue + ")"
        .Range("A3:C3").Value = Array("Ticker", "Total Daily Volume", "Return")
        .Range("A4").Resize(tickerIndex, 3) = ticker
    End With
    endTime = Timer
    MsgBox "This code ran in " & Format(endTime - startTime, "0.0") & _
           " seconds for the year " & (yearValue)
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I will certainly try this out!